# How using ssh/scp between non-public machines

Tags: ssh, lan, ssl, scp

I am often in the following situation:

I have two machines, A and B, which are on LANs, and have non-public IP addresses. Machine C is on the same LAN as B, but publicly visible. I would like to copy a file from B to A, so I have to:

- ssh to C
- ssh from C to B
- scp file from B to C
- scp file from C to A

Given that ssl can do wonderful things with tunnelling displays all the way back from B to A via C transparently, it seems like it should be possible to do the same with files.

Is there a way to use standard ssh/scp to copy from B to A, without having to make a temporary copy on C?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This site for programming questions, and your question is more suited for http://superuser.com. I have voted to move it there; after five people vote it will move automatically.

Answer (score 3):

You want to set up port forwarding. When you SSH from machine A to machine B add a tunnel, i.e. add -L 1234:A:22 when tunnelling to B. Then SSH to machine C and scp the files to B on port 1234 (i.e. add -P 1234 to scp). This will actually route to port 22 on machine A which is the ssh port and hence it'll transfer directly.

I don't have three machines with which to try this right now but I think this should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you can ssh from C to B and scp to A from C, then I think you should be able to use scp directly from C.

(Using aa.aa.aa.aa as A's IP address and bb.bb.bb.bb as B's IP address)

- ssh into C
- At the command line on C:

  `scp bb.bb.bb.bb:/path/to/file aa.aa.aa.aa:/path/to/destination`

Comment: You beat me by 5 seconds.

Comment: This might not work. If the user can ssh from A -> C, but not from C -> A, the original method described would work, but my solution won't.